# Oracle error: TNS: Listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA

Tags: oracle, vb6, oracle11g

I have installed Oracle 11 G client(Administrator option) in my machine Windows 7 64 bit.

This the path of the oracle home

```
C:\app\anoop2\product\11.2.0\client_1
```

"Path" of environment variables are also pointing to

```
C:\app\anoop2\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;
C:\app\anoop2\product\11.2.0\client_1;
```

Now, though i am able to connect to server through my SQL developer, i am not able to connect it using VB 6. This is the code i am using

> ```
> Dim aConn As ADODB.Connection
>  Set aConn = New ADODB.Connection
>  aConn.Open "PROVIDER=MSDAORA.1;PASSWORD=XXX;User ID=XXX;Data Source=XXX;Persist Security Info=True"
> ```

This is my tnsnames.ora file

> DEV =   (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST =
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXX)(PORT = 1521))
>       )
>       (CONNECT_DATA =
>         (SERVICE_NAME = DEV)
>       )   )

I am not able to find a listener file in my machine. I am getting an error "TNS: Listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA". Any pointers and suggestions are really appreciated.

Thanks,
Anoop

Comment: Please check your environment one more time.
C:\>dir /s/b tnsnames.ora
C:\>echo %PATH%
C:\>sqlplus system@DEV

Data Source=DEV or you can also try:
Data Source= (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXX)(PORT = 1521)) ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = DEV) ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check listener log and verify service name in DBA_SERVICES view. In your setup, double check "Data Source" value

Comment: I was giving the IP address, instead of service_name as the datasource in my connection string. Corrected that, and things started to work. Thanks